# Safely pass variables from one php file to another php file in the URL

Tags: php

This might be a basic question and I've been searching for a safe and clean way to do this. Im passing a normal string which CAN include special characters (like $ ^ % etc). How can I do this in the url? For example I have a variable called $text which In addto.php from $_GET. How do I then transfer this to more.php?

Comment: Are you passing this back to your own server? You could consider session variables instead, so you never have to communicate the data to the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'more.php?varname='.urlencode($_GET['text']);
```

Comment: how would I receive this in more.php ...would I have to decode? and how would I place this in addto.php specifically?

Comment: in this example you get it by using $_GET['varname'].

Comment: @Praneet Sharma Are you trying to add it into a link to addto.php or a redirect?

Comment: Im trying to send $text to more.php so more.php can echo the result ( just to test)

Comment: I think you're probably trying to do this with a link. In that case you want something like: `echo '<a href="more.php?test='.urlencode($_GET['text']).'">More</a>';` in addto.php

Comment: If you want to do a redirect it'd be more like `header('location: more.php?test='.urlencode($_GET['text']));` before any output on addto.php

Comment: ok that works...but how would I automatically go to more.php...I have to click on the link

Comment: The second method, with the `header` is a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) sounds like what you want.

(from the docs)

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data through an URL, it should be in the form of key/value pairs, but you shouldn't use it to pass too much data because an URL has a limit. You also should not pass sensitive information.

A key/value pair is something like this:

```
key=value
```

If you have more then one pair, you need to separate them using the *&* char. Here is an example:

```
myScript.php?color1=blue&color2=red
```

The string after *?* is called the *Query String*. With PHP you can easily access those key/value pairs using the super-global $_GET. So, in myScript.php you do:

```
$a = $_GET['color1'];
$b = $_GET['color2'];
```

Now, if you are going to create a dynamic query string, you should use `urlencode()` at least, so any special characters will be translated to maintain a proper URL format.

Please read the following:

http://php.net/urlencode

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)